# List of elements gets overridden in angular js when using in dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs

[image]

[image]

I want to show a hierarchy like in the image. I am able to create this hierarchy and I want to show the second level elements in a dropdown. However, while doing this the hierarchy value gets overrided with dropdown value and hence I am not able to show the third level of hierarchy.

This is my Dropdown html page:

Business Domain
                        
    
OK

This is my controller:

```
controller('domainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'DomainNameService', function($scope, $state, DomainNameService) {  
    $scope.busdomain = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
    /*For populating the domain values Which I am fetching from service
      Attached the json image*/
         var domainList=DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
            if(domainList!=null){
                 domainList[0].childNode.sort();
                for (var i = 0; i < domainList[0].childNode.length; i++) {
                    if (domainList[0].childNode[i].name!=null) {
                        var name=domainList[0].childNode[i].name;
                     domainList[0].childNode.splice(i,1,name);//for replacing the object with name as I have to show name in dropdown list
                      $scope.busdomainname=domainList[0].childNode;//got the list of name but after this my service list also get overrides
                $scope.busdomainname.sort();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.busdomainname=$scope.busdomain[0].childNode;//Added for getting business domain list
        $scope.busdomainname.sort();
            }
        }
        }

    $scope.addSubDomainTree = function(val){

            var varType = "busSubDomain";
            var domain=[];
            var busDomain=$scope.bussubdomain;
            var parent = DomainNameService.getDomainName()[0];
            //Done some code here to get the hierarchy
            DomainNameService.setBusDomain($scope.statements);
            $scope.domain.domainName = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName[0];
            $state.go('BusDomainTree', null, { reload: true });//fix for refresh issue.
            }
        }

}
```

This is my Service Method

```
setChildBD: function(varType,childBD,value,val){
        if(varType == "busSubDomain"){
            this.error=undefined;
            if(childSubDomainName.indexOf(childBD)==-1){
                childSubDomainName.push(childBD);
                var i= childDomainName.indexOf(val);
//Done this for replacing the object name with an array which contains the child.attached the image for its value
                 childDomainName.splice(i,1,value.childNode[0]);

            }

      },
getBusDomainName: function(){
        return this.busDomainValue;//here the busDomainValue gets overrided with the controller list value
    },
```

[image]

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Better create a clean plunkr or fiddle that would give us better idea..

Comment: Got a solution for this. I used
 var domainList=angular.copy($scope.busdomain) instead of        
 var domainList=DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
in controller.js

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for this. I used var domainList=angular.copy($scope.busdomain) instead of var domainList=DomainNameService.getBusDomainName(); in controller.js –